# mysql query 2 tables with count

Tags: php, mysql, count

Hi i have the following query/table from a local bookstore

```
$queryadmin ="SELECT last_name, first_name, user_id FROM users";
$recordz = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $queryadmin);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($recordz, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
echo '<tr>
<td align="left">' . $row['first_name'] . '</td>
<td align="left">' . $row['last_name'] . '</td>
<td align="left">' . $row['user_id'] . '</td>
</tr>'
;}
```

now i want an additional column from another table where the numbers of books each user has lend out are displayed. 
So the query *if nested seperately* would go something like this

```
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT FROM mirror3 WHERE userid='".$row['user_id']."'", $link); 
$anzahl = mysql_num_rows($query2);
```

placing this query nested inside the while query (right after while starting) from above does not work. How to do that?

> supplied argument is not a valid MySQL
>   result resource

thanks

Comment: Is it intended that the last sql statement in the post is not valid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is wrong. Specify a field name:

> $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT
>   **SOMETHING** FROM mirror3 WHERE userid='".$row['user_id']."'", $link);

Comment: omg, you are right. OMG i can do nested queries. even if this seems to be only for non-pro's like me only ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do this in one query:

```
$query = mysqli_query('SELECT u.last_name, u.first_name, u.user_id, m.PUT_SOMETHING_HERE
        FROM users u
        LEFT JOIN mirror3 m ON u.user_id = m.userid
        WHERE m.PUT_SOMETHING_HERE IS NOT NULL');
```

But Parkyprg has a point, you need to be selecting something from that second query.

Comment: hi. thx. i frequently use join but i have no clue how to do a count on the other query with a where clause. could you add that on your example (m.PUT_SOMETHING_HERE)? the problem i see is that the query statement for the second table is completely different than for the first table. I used mysql_num_rows

Comment: Hmm... I guess you could do something like `SELECT u.last_name, u.first_name, u.user_id, COUNT(m.PUT_SOMETHING_HERE) AS count FROM users u LEFT JOIN mirror3 m ON u.user_id = m.userid WHERE m.PUT_SOMETHING_HERE IS NOT NULL GROUP BY u.user_id` but this is only a guess. If this doesn't work, stick with your accepted solution